# How can i mock an inherited method of the class i am testing

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, powermock

I have code similar to this

```
class Util{
 public String transform(String str);
 //lots of logic including ajax calls
 return("Modified"+str);
 }
 public caseChange(String str){
 //lots of logic including ajax calls
 return str.toUpperCase()      
 }

class TextParser extends Util{
 public String parse(str)
//lots of logic to modify str
 str = caseChange(str);
 //some more logic to modify str
return transform(str);
}
```

Is there anyway to mock the caseChange and transform methods to return some mocked data and prevent a call to the superclass when i call

```
String result = new TextParser().parse("hello")
```

in the unit test class to assert result.

The transform and changeCase are over simplified in my example. In reality they perform ajax calls and there is a ton of other logic. I want to mock them out so that can unit test just this part an then unit test the super methods later

Answer (score 1):

In your given example: you simply don't do that. Your methods are **only** working on your inputs; so it should absolutely **not** matter where those methods are implemented.

In other words: it seems most appropriate for you to focus on **contract checking** tests only. Like:

```
@Test
public testWhatever() {
  assertThat(new TextParser.parse("hello"), is("expected output"));
}
```

Yes, you *can* probably mock such things using Mockito/Powermock; but you shouldn't! You see, your production code is directly calling those methods; so you **want** to test that calling *parse* gives you expected results (while using all the code that will also run in a production setup!)

Edit: given your comment about that methods being "complicated". Then I suggest: do **not** use inheritance here. You should **not** make class B a subclass of A just to have easy access to some methods. In other words: inheritance is about *modeling* an IS-A relation. So, a *TextParser* is a *Util*? Doesn't sound very convincing.

Thus: you better turn to *composition* here. Your *TextParser* should *use* a *Util* object. And that one can be provided via dependency injection; and your need to mock with *inherited* methods vanishes completely!

Comment: The transform and changeCase are over simplified in my example. In reality they perform ajax calls and there is a ton of other logic. I want to mock them out so that can unit test just this part an then unit test the super methods later

Answer (score 1):

You may need to create another subclass like

```
class TextParserForTest extends TextParser {
      @Override
      public String parse(String str)  {
              super.parse(str);
      }

      @Override
      public String caseChange(String str) {
              return "whatever";
      }
}
```

---

edit :  use mockito to this :

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

import org.junit.Test;

@Test
public void test() {
    TextParser tp = mock(TextParser.class);

    // all the methods that you want to test
    when(tp.parse(any())).thenCallRealMethod();
    when... 

    // all the methods that you want to mock
    when(tp.caseChange(any()).thenReturn("whatever");
    when... 
}
```

Comment: i have to write 25 test cases per class :( 
is there any way to do it with powermock or mockito?

Comment: try when(textParse.caseChange(anyString()).thenReturn("whatever");

Comment: i tried that with a new Util and TextParser  object. it Still goes to the super class

Comment: I added something, you can try it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the spy functionality of Mockito. The spy calls real methods unless they are stubbed.

```
@Test
public void testParse() {   
    TextParser textParser = Mockito.spy(new TextParser());          
    when(textParser.caseChange(Matchers.anyString())).thenReturn("mocked");
    Assert.assertEquals("Modifiedmocked", textParser.parse("hello"));
}
```